# Restart a Perl Script on Error? (Perl Newbie)

Tags: perl, error-handling, twitter-streaming-api

I am using AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream module obtained from CPAN.  I am also new to Perl, and this script which I modified from the example fires an event to insert a bit of twitter data into a database once a tweet is read from the Twitter streaming API based on some conditions.  I have redacted some of the code, but the general information is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream;

    use DBI;
    use DBD::mysql;



    my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

    my($user, $password, $method, $args) = @ARGV;
    # my twitter login
    my %args;
    if ($method eq 'follow') {
        $args{follow} = $args;
        $method = 'filter';
    } elsif ($method eq 'track') {
        $args{track}  = $args;
        $method = 'filter';
    }

    binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

    my $streamer = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
        username => $user,
        password => $password,
        timeout => 0,
        method   => $method || "sample",
        %args,
        on_keepalive => sub {
              warn "ping\n";
          },
        on_tweet => sub {

            my $DBIconnect;
            #db connection info

            my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:$host:$dbport";

            $DBIconnect = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);

            my $tweet = shift;

            if($tweet->{id}) {
               # occasionally twitter 
               # insert some data here

                my $save_tweet = $query;
                #print $query;
                my $save_handle = $DBIconnect->prepare($save_tweet);

                if($save_handle->execute()) { 
                    #print "Tweet #" . $tweet->{id} . " Stored\n";
                } else { 
                    #print "Error Saving Tweet #" . $tweet->{id} . "\n";
                }
                $save_handle->finish();
                $DBIconnect->disconnect();
            } else { 
                #print "Tweet did not contain Tweet ID.\n";
            }

        },
        on_error => sub {
            my $error = shift;
            print "Error! Error!";
            warn "ERROR: $error";


            $done->send;
            sleep 2;

            $done->recv;
        },
        on_eof   => sub {
            $done->send;
        },
    );


    $done->recv;
```

In this process, occasionally the stream or application will quit for reasons that still mystify me.  I would like to simply wait for 3 seconds, then restart the entire perl script (or simply the AnyEvent instance) to continue reading data.

You might notice that I attempted this with:

```
    on_error => sub {
        my $error = shift;
        print "Error! Error!";
        warn "ERROR: $error";


        $done->send;
        sleep 2;

        $done->recv;
    },
```

This doesn't seem to restart the process.  Could anyone provide me any insight of what this would take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the module, but you need to be clearer on what "the stream or application will quit for reasons that still mystify me" means. Does the script die?

If so, one way to catch the error and restart is to wrap the entire code in eval as follows:

```
my $continue = 1;
while ($continue) {
   eval {  # Catch "die" event
       my $streamer = xxx
       # some other call to start the streamer???
   };
   if ($@ =~ /specific error message substring you wish to restart on/) {
       # Do some prep work if needed
   } else {
       $continue = 0; # quit on next loop iteration
       # As alternative to using $continue flag, just do:
       # last; 
   }
}
```

Comment: The perl script will exit (stop receiving) when the event on_error is called.  Your solution seems to generally cover the underlying problem, which is the streaming module basically says ERROR: (which is what I want to catch) and then exits.  I guess I don't use evals in PHP.  Thanks!

Comment: @Zack - `eval` in its block form (google "perldoc eval") traps `DIE` signal, so any `die` statement that performs error handling from within that module would - instead of crashing your script - merely exit from `eval` and set the die error message contents into `$@`.